# How can I use IBMPlexMono-Italic font on VSCode for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, fonts, visual-studio-code

I've installed (from Google fonts) and configured this one on VSCode of macOS, then it works well.

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'IBMPlexMono-Italic', 'Fira Code', sans-serif",
```

But I do the same thing on Windows 10, with the newest version of VSCode, but it doesn't work. Already tried with Github build source, it doesn't work also.

How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 10, the font names are different. For `IBMPlexMono`, you need to change it to `IBM Plex Mono`. See below:

Change this:
`"editor.fontFamily": "'IBMPlexMono', 'Fira Code', sans-serif",`

to:
`"editor.fontFamily": "'IBM Plex Mono', 'Fira Code', sans-serif",`.

Kindly note, some of the fonts do not work (correctly) on VS Code.

The italic based font do not work at the moment. These are the lists of working font types in their right name for VS Code.

```
IBM Plex Mono Bold
IBM Plex Mono ExtraLight
IBM Plex Mono Light
IBM Plex Mono Medium
IBM Plex Mono (Same as Regular)
IBM Plex Mono Semi Bold
IBM Plex Mono Thin
```

Comment: Yes, I already tried before and the regular still works but I would like to use the Italic.